# MySQL insert fails

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

I am trying to create and insert into 2 tables on sqlfiddle.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Submissions` (
  `sub_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `hacker_id` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `score` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `sub_date` Date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sub_id`,`hacker_id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `Submissions` (`sub_id`, `hacker_id`, `score`, `sub_date`) VALUES
  ('18833', '962', '12', '2019-12-07'),
  ('35892', '962', '45', '2019-12-07');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Hacker` (
  `hacker_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(`hacker_id`, `name`)
  )

INSERT INTO `Hacker` (`hacker_id`, `name`) VALUES
('123','Bob');
```

The insert into Submissions works fine. I do not understand what is wrong with my Insert into Hacker which fails.

Fiddle is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d4d786 but refreshing drops the second insert, I'm guessing because it fails to compile/build/whatever the term is in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `;` after your second `CREATE TABLE` statement.  It should look like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Submissions` (
  `sub_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `hacker_id` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `score` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `sub_date` Date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sub_id`,`hacker_id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `Submissions` (`sub_id`, `hacker_id`, `score`, `sub_date`) VALUES
  ('18833', '962', '12', '2019-12-07'),
  ('35892', '962', '45', '2019-12-07');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Hacker` (
  `hacker_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(`hacker_id`, `name`)
  );

INSERT INTO `Hacker` (`hacker_id`, `name`) VALUES
('123','Bob');
```